# Homeworldsmate - Blastdoor

Tags: board-games, outer-space, homeworlds

Back with another **[one move wonder homeworldsmate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57007/homeworldsmate-inheritance-or-insurance-fraud)** (link explains who Lee is, for example. Though I guess I'll explain here anyway.)

quick reminder, remember to use [these rules](http://www.looneylabs.com/rules/homeworlds), with the additional note that any action is optional, because I think that's what the rules say but it's kinda vague.

## Lee wins in 1

[image: ![enter image description here]

You like that background nebula decoration? I used gimp for like the first time (excepting one practice run) to do that. Either way it's my <s>first</s> second image exported from gimp (I made an edit to the puzzle just now). Not super high quality...

If you're just joining us, Lee is the player on the left. Her pieces are above their star systems, her pieces point away from the left, and she owns the homeworld on the left. **Le**e = **Le**ft for a possible person who didn't make the connection. Ray is the other player

Again, Lee won't be able to trade the yellow for a red, because the reds of that size are already all on the board, however, they're all owned by Ray this time, and the only way to catastrophise them would be eliminating Ray anyway.

Anyway, I've got the right ruleset this time (hopefully), so we should be fine as long as insolubility goes.

Like the other 1 move homeworldsmate, this has a unique solution (I'm pretty sure. don't sue me if I messed up the rules again).

#### Bonus round: explain the meaning of the (sub)title

Text version

```
key: type of piece (stars or ships, left and right): quantity if >1 colour size (size as a number/pip count)
```

```
Lee's Homeworld: stars: Yellow large (3), Blue medium (2)
                 Lee's ships: 2 Blue smalls (1), Green small (1), Red small (1)
                 Ray's ships: None

Ray's homeworld: stars: Blue small (1), Red medium (2)
                 Lee's ships: Yellow medium (2)
                 Ray's ships: 2 Red mediums (2)

System 001: star: Red small (1)
            Lee's ships: Blue large (3)
            Ray's ships: None

Also there's a cool nebula in the background behind the pieces.
```

I'm gonna tag this outer-space because consistency, again. game of space kings. Maybe Lee and Ray live in outerspace. Who knows? I guess I'll remove the tag if there's an issue though.

Comment: [Inkscape](https://youtu.be/zUIOEXssTSE) should be better suited for these type of images than Gimp.

Comment: yeah but I actually just used gimp to make a mask over the nebula, not the actual drawing

Comment: That image [looks familiar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg)...

Comment: I created an Inkscape template which is linked in [my puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/57084/15632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Sacrifice Y2 to get 2 move actions.
>   - Move B3 back to Lees Homeworld. Declare a catastrophe in Lees Homeworld and remove the blue pieces there. This also removes the **blast door B2** which prevented access to Rays Homeworld. Both Homeworlds are now connected.
>   - Move R1 to Rays Homeworld. Declare a catastrophe in Rays Homeworld and remove the red pieces there. Lee wins.

Comment: nice work. on another note, I think I might have to develop a notation for moves, if one has not already been made.

Comment: Also you might like to go for the bonus round.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Better now? Btw. I found [this](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1764731/homeworlds-game-notation) but I'm not sure it will be helpful on this site.

Comment: Not exactly the reasoning I had for the title. Blastdoor is a little bit more metaphorical. might be better as Blast door

Comment: Re "notation for moves," there are at least two (SDG's and mine). In mine (which permits "incomplete" or "deduced" moves) the winning move would be `sac y2 Ray; move b3 to Lee; cat blue; move r1 to Ray; cat red`. See https://github.com/Quuxplusone/Homeworlds/blob/master/pythonsrc/tests.py for more examples. (But I also don't adhere to the ruleset that permits mid-turn catastrophes!)