# Homeworlds: War Games

Tags: board-games, outer-space, homeworlds

Here's my second Homeworlds problem! (My first was [Homeworlds: Mini Doomsday Machine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98604/homeworlds-mini-doomsday-machine).)

[image]

```
Lee (0,g3b2) y2g1-
Ray (1,r2) r2-y3y3y3
DS1 (y1) -y1g3
Y (y2) r1-y1
G (g2) r2-g2
R (r3) g1-r1
B (b3) r1-b1
```

The stash contains `r3r3 y2 g3g2g1 b3b3b2b2b1b1`.

> So... it is down to me, and it is down to you.
>
> If you capture my red ship, you threaten to invade with r1r1.
>
> If you capture my yellow ship, you threaten to invade with y1.
>
> If you capture my green ship, you threaten to build r3r3.
>
> If you capture my blue ship, you threaten to trade r2 for y2.
>
> The battle of wits has begun. It ends when you decide and we both move, and we find out who is right... and who is dead.

Lee to play and mate in 1. (That is, you must find the unique move which Lee can make, such that no matter what Ray replies, Lee will win on the very next turn.)

Comment: @melfnt Why that edit? Homeworlds isn't a video game, and we have enough puzzles about it that it makes sense for it to have its own tag.

Comment: (I've rolled the edit back.) It'd be nice for someone to tag the other Homeworlds puzzles with [homeworlds], btw. I tried doing that myself but got shot down.

Comment: If I had 2k rep here, I'd do it myself.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica there are only two puzzles tagged [homeworlds] and that tag does not even have description nor excerpt. My bad I didn't know it is not a videogame

Comment: @melfnt: If you look at the related items in the right sidebar (especially the ones explicitly linked from "Mini Doomsday Machine"), you'll find 4 more Homeworlds puzzles without the [homeworlds] tag.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I added the tags just now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homeworlds is new to me, so please forgive any misunderstandings or mistakes :)

Proposed solution:

> Sacrifice `g1` at `R` to build `r3` at `Ray`.
>
>
>  This creates a powerful threat of sacrifice `y2` at `Lee` to move one of several red ships (`r1` at `Y`, `r1` at `B` or `r2` at `G`) to `Ray` which wins by a red catastrophe.
>
>
>  Ray can't remove the red ships already at `Ray`. (Catastrophe is clearly not an option, and capturing the ships will leave them in place.)
>
>
>  Ray has only an `r1` red ship, so can't capture all three of Lee's red ships that threaten to invade `Ray`. It is also impossible to eliminate all the attackers by catastrophe.
>
>
>  The only way Ray can cause trouble at `Lee` is by catastrophe. This is possible by sacrificing `y3` at `Ray` to move `g3` at `DS1` and `g2` at `G` into `Lee`. This catastrophe leaves the `y2` as the last defender of the homeworld which can't be sacrificed on the following turn[*]. This seems to be the only defense. (Conveniently, this also defends the alternate threat of sacrifice `g1` at `Lee` to build `r3` at `Ray`.)
>
>
>  However, Lee can now win with a sacrifice of `r2` at `G` to capture both remaining defenders of `Ray`.
>
>
>  [*] If I understand the rules correctly, this sacrifice would be allowed if Lee used it to move another ship back to `Lee` by the end of the turn, but there is no ship close enough to do this and also press the attack.

Refutations of some alternatives:

> Sacrificing `g1` at `Lee` to build `r3` at `Ray` doesn't work as above, as sacrificing `y2` is no longer possible and thus not a threat. There is another threat to cause catastrophe at `Ray` by sacrificing `g1` at `R` to build the last `r3`, but this can be refuted by capturing `g1`, building `r3`, or exploring `r3`.
>
>
>  Simply capturing at `R` or `Y` can be refuted by the catastrophe line pinning `y2` at `Lee` (as there is no capture threat at `Ray`).
>
>
>  Simply capturing at `B` or `G` is refuted by capturing at `Ray`.
>
>
>  Sacrificing `r2` at `G` for a double threat is more convincing, but the catastrophe line defends them all simultaneously. (It defends the trade threat by sacrificing `y3`.)
>
>
>  Sacrificing `y2` at `Lee` actually loses to the catastrophe.

Comment: Correct! FWIW, I didn't understand what you meant by "all three attackers" at first. You might clarify that by "attackers" you mean the three red ships mentioned 2 paragraphs earlier. Saying "potential attackers" or "threatening ships" would be an improvement, too; colloquially I would call a ship "attacking" only if it were already in a contested system, threatening a _capture_ action on its next turn. (Of course there's no _formal_ definition of "attacking" in Homeworlds, but that's how I'd informally interpret the word.) Other than that wording nit, this looks like a perfect analysis!

Comment: I showed the problem to one of my game buddies this Monday; we solved it together in less than 20 minutes, after I refuted some of his answers. If no answer had been formulated today, I would've entered it. Despite the number of hours I spent, it was definitely worth it. And @tehtmi, you are certainly on your way to get better at this game!

Answer (score 0):

Am I the first with a good idea? Here is my second attempt:

> Lee: `S G1 Lee / B R3 Ray`
>  Lee threatens to build another Red with a sac of his G1 at R. So, Ray will capture the G1.
>  Ray: `C G1 R`, however,
>  Lee: `C G2 G` -- Lee has now potentially two builds. Can Ray build the last Red to prevent Lee from building Red? Well, Ray has only Red in R and in his HW. So, he must build it at R. 
>  Ray: `B R3 R` -- But now Lee can move his R1 from Y to R: 
>  Lee: `M R1 Y R / Cat R R` -- and now the Bank contains 4 Reds. No matter what Ray does now, Lee will build 2 Reds at his next move. 
>  Ray: `C R3 Ray` (this prevents a double capture) 
>  Lee: `S G2 G / B R Ray / B R Ray / Cat R Ray / GO`.

Yes, this is an EXTREMELY difficult problem. But can Lee even win if Ray has an R3 as part of his HW and an R2 (instead of an R1) at R?

Comment: Sadly, incorrect. After Lee's first move, Ray could prevent your continuation via "sac r1 at R; capture r2 at Ray"... oh wait, also, Lee does not have a g2 at G! The g2 at G is Ray's ship, not Lee's.

Comment: @Quuxplusone How do you make an unscalable font? I couldn't align everything nice, like in your example. If I know how to, I will align the moves.

Comment: By "unscalable font" you mean monospace/teletype `like this`? Put backticks around it, or indent a whole paragraph four spaces. You can also "edit" my question to see its exact Markdown code (and then cancel or close your browser tab instead of submitting the edit, of course). Also, add 2 spaces at the end of a line to create a linebreak — or just use an HTML `<br>`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone OK, I tried. It's better. And, also, did you see the new solution? Thx.

Comment: Second attempt: Better, but still incomplete. IIUC, you're describing a line of play that leads to `GO` (Game Over), but only on Lee's 4th move, whereas the puzzle asks for the play that inevitably leads to `GO` on Lee's _2nd_ move (plus a proof that it is inevitable; i.e., you should demonstrate that you've considered _all_ of Ray's possible replies). Bonus nerdsnipe puzzle: You imply that Ray _must_ reply to `sac G1 Lee / build R3 Ray` with `capture G1 R` or else lose immediately; but I believe I see at least one other possible reply!

Comment: Btw, if you make a third attempt, I recommend doing it as a new answer, not an edit on this answer, because every edit you make to this answer invalidates my old comments. If you ever get it right, the "Sadly, incorrect" comment will be sadly incorrect!

Comment: @Quuxplusone OK. Accepted. I wondered if perhaps I misunderstood that after Lee's first move, Ray is bound to lose (rather than say after Ray's second move, but then, Ray will also lose after Lee's first move . . . ). So, there is a shorter solution? Sheesh. I've spent more than 4 hours already on this puzzle. Not that I complain, on the contrary, but that's why I'm saying it's *extremely* difficult. Well, that's actually meant as a huge compliment . . . :-)

Comment: B.t.w., I did not mean that Ray doesn't have any other move options, but that any other move will also lose. I'm not sure how long the answer is going to be . . . But OK. I will leave this answer here for others to consider as you suggest. And, the "sadly incorrect" comment is already sadly incorrect for what follows . . . (not referring to the same solution).

Comment: @Quuxplusone Nerdsnipe. Yes, I see it. Ray could sac one of his Greens and build the last R3. But then, I gather, Lee will sac his R2 at Ray and capture 2 Y3 ships with his R3. Then on Lee's next turn, he can sac the R3 at Ray and capture the other remaining ship(s). Correct? Btw. We agree that Ray is lost no matter what . . .

Comment: @Quuxplusone Now, the reason for my "suboptimal" solution is that I don't believe it's possible for Lee to win at his second move. But to not spoil this for others, I will put it also as an answer and see what comes of it. Needless to say, I'm totally intrigued!

Comment: @Quuxplusone It worked! When I was going over the reasons why I believed it couldn't work at all, I found the small opening through which Lee could win!

Answer (score 0):

I finally see it. It was a real challenge. Wow.

> Lee `S R1 Y / C G2 G`
>  Now, I solved the problem of the Bank. Lee has a G2 to build 2 Red ships in Ray, unless Ray builds at least 2 Red ships. But to do that, Ray has to sac his G3. Can Ray build 3 ships? Well, yes, he could build all of them at R and not call catastrophe, but Lee will be able to at the start of his turn. So, perhaps he needs only to build 2 Red ships? Again only at R, otherwise Lee could build the last ship at Ray.
>  Ray `S G3 DS1 / B R1 R / B R3 R`
>  Lee `Cat R R / S G2 G / B R Ray / B R Ray / GO`

Comment.

> I tried to prevent the Green invasion. If I don't, then Ray can invade Lee. In fact, Ray can always sac a Yellow, and Lee can not cause a Yellow Overpopulation in Ray. So, Lee must somehow get 2 Red ships to Ray.

Thanks for this one! Great, great, great.

Comment: Thanks... but still not right. :) Let's say Lee does `sac r1 Y; capture g2 G`, intending to build two red ships at `Ray` on his next turn. You're right that Ray can't prevent that by building out the red stash; but Ray has _another_ way to prevent Lee from building two red ships at `Ray`!

Comment: @quuxplusone. I see. Ray `C R2 Ray` prevents the use of Lee's G2. I'm stumped.